# Populating a Table with values determined from a recursive query

Tags: sql

Pre-cursor:  I am very new at trying to code.

Problem:  I am trying to create a query that will determine cumulative cycletimes for products.  The issue that I am having is that the data is structured in the tables in such a way that you have to determine what flows have children by continuing to drill through the BOM.

Example:

[image: Table Example]

Items in column 2 that are FD are children of a parent, but are also parents themselves.  I need to be able to identify them  and then get to their children as well in the same query.

I am wondering what the most efficient way to do that is.

Thank you.

Comment: . . Tag your question with the databaseyou are using.

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?